# What are the differences among the sentences when "make", "cause" and "tend" are used?

Tags: grammar

Context:
1: **I would "make" you to go from here.**
2: **I would "cause" you to think.**
3: **I would "tend" you to think.**

Comment: The verbs are not related. And "tend you to think" is a mistake. Tend cannot take an indirect object. What makes you ask about them like this?

Comment: 2nd one is correct?

Comment: Repeat: tend to think is a mistake.